# Underlying values in DT table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to underline values in DT table . Example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("iris")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$iris <- renderDataTable(datatable(head(iris)))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the above application, is there a way to underline any values ? (example value (2,3) , meaning 2nd row and 3rd column value)

Comment: Hi Friends, Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(DT)

underlineCells <- function(rows, cols){
  stopifnot(length(rows) == length(cols))
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  var rows = [%s];", paste0(rows-1, collapse = ",")),
    sprintf("  var cols = [%s];", paste0(cols, collapse = ",")),
    "  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i){",
    "    if(index == rows[i]){",
    "      $('td:eq(' + cols[i] + ')', row)",
    "        .css({'text-decoration': 'underline'});",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"
  )
}
datatable(iris,
          options = list(
            dom = "t",
            rowCallback = JS(underlineCells(c(1,3), c(2,1)))
          )
)
```

[image]